# Finding 1812 Virginia militia records

Tags: united-states, military-records, virginia

I have an ancestor who served in the Virginia militia during the War of 1812.

What is a good resource to learn more about this military unit?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE!  This is a very broad question.  What do you want to know?  In the [help], [What kinds of questions should I avoid asking?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) says "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Comment: Would asking if this unit was involved in the battle of Washington, DC be better? Or can I ask which battles the unit was in?

Comment: Yes, that's much better.  Your basic question is not really "what is a good resource" but "how do I find X?"  The more specific a question you can ask, the easier it is to figure out how to answer it.

Comment: Likewise welcome to G&FH SE!  As food for thought I had a question about a British military unit of similar vintage and structured it like this: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/5514/finding-late-18th-century-service-record-of-soldier-william-hobbs-in-somersetshi